# Different Controller extends different template in Kohana

Tags: php, templates, controller, kohana, extend

i have a kohana based website and many controllers.

I want that some controllers (and automatically the afferent views) to extend (and use) a different template (some other template than the default one).

What have i done for that?

1. I have created a new controller named let's say new_template
2. The controller class has the signature:

   abstract class Controller_Admintemplate extends Kohana_Controller_Template
3. i have created a new view for the new template: newtemplate.php ()

The problem: the views associated with the controllers that extend the new template, are not dislaying using the new template.

Where i am wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these three and you'll be okey. =]

http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/tutorials/templates